# How can I determine if process is 32 or 64Bit from a handle?

Tags: c, winapi

How can I get the information from a Process handle acquired using OpenProcess whether a Process is 32 or 64 Bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, IsWow64Process is annoyingly useless.  It really means "is 32-bit emulation enabled" and that returns false if you run on a 32-bit operating system, it doesn't need any emulation.

You'll only get a good value out of it if you know for a fact that you're running on a 64-bit operating system.  Which is tricky to find out.  The IntPtr.Size == 8 test proofs that you run 64-bit, but it doesn't proof that it is definitely *not* a 64-bit operating system.  The 64-bit version of the framework might not have been installed.  Or your code might be running from an .exe that had the Platform Target forced to x86.  Which is *not* uncommon for code that's interested in bitness.

You'll need to P/Invoke GetNativeSystemInfo().  If that throws (or GetProcAddress returns IntPtr.Zero), you know for a fact that it is a 32-bit operating system.  If it doesn't, inspect the value of SYSTEM_INFO.wProcessorArchitecture.  It will be 9 for x64, 6 for Titanium, 0 for x86.  So if you get 9, then use IsWow64Process.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declarations.

Note that the new .NET 4.0 Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem is flawed the same way.

Comment: The only problem with it is that GetNativeSystemInfo according to MSDN is supported from WinXP upwards, regardless of architecture. Also, I don't have a machine without AMD64/EMT64 at hand, but doesn't wProcessorArchitecture correspond to the Processor Architecure and not the one of the System installed?

edit: i dunno why you guys make the effort to give .net solutions when i tagged it with C and WinAPI, just saying

Comment: Well, you don't need P/Invoke then.  Given that you have the right processor to test this, you can answer your own question in about 10 minutes?

Comment: Okay, checked SYSTEM_INFO.wProcessorArchitecture and it corresponds to the information of the system and not of the cpu, so this solution works, thanks.

Comment: Good.  Beware that you *have* to use GetProcAddress() in your C code or your program won't run on early operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can test it using following code:

```
     bool is64BitProcess = (IntPtr.Size == 8);
     bool is64BitOperatingSystem = is64BitProcess || InternalCheckIsWow64();

     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention =  CallingConvention.Winapi)]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
       public static extern bool IsWow64Process(
       [In] IntPtr hProcess,
       [Out] out bool wow64Process
   );

     [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static bool InternalCheckIsWow64()
    {
         if ((Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1) ||
    Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
           {
             using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
               {
                    bool retVal;
                    if (!IsWow64Process(p.Handle, out retVal))
                    {
                       return false;
                    }
                    return retVal;
               }
           }
            else
            {
                  return false;
         }
 }
```

Comment: +1, link to the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That's also what i thought at first, but this function just determines if the process runs under WoW64, means a 32Bit process under a 64Bit OS, I tested this with WinXP SP3 and it gave me false because it was a 32Bit Process not running under W0W64.

Answer (score 0):

This is [C code](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/8871e3362feaa4ae69763a9212cdfbb4a814e54b/psutil/_psutil_windows.c#L3498) with some Python involved but it gives you an idea.
Here's a polished version:

```
int is64bit(long pid) {
    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    BOOL isWow64;

    // if OS is not 64 bit, no process will be either    
    GetNativeSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
    if (sysinfo.wProcessorArchitecture != PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64) 
        return 0;

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);;
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return -1;

    if (! IsWow64Process(hProcess, &isWow64)) {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return -1;
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    if (isWow64)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```